# Django: How to compare two querysets and get the difference without including the PK

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-queryset, set-difference

I don't think the word `difference` is correct because you might think `difference()` but it makes sense to me what I am trying to achieve. I do apologize if this is a common problem that's already been solved but I can't find a solution or dumbed down understanding of it.

I have two querysets of the same model as follows:

```
qs1 = ErrorLog.objects.get(report=original_report).defer('report') # 272 rows returned
qs2 = ErrorLog.objects.get(report=new_report).defer('report')      # 266 rows returned
```

I want to compare the first one to the second one and find the `6` rows that don't match in the first `qs1`

I tried `difference()` and `intersection()` but I keep ending up with the same `272` rows or `0` rows. I have a feeling that it sees `pk` as a unique value so it never finds matching rows. I tried the following:

```
# Get the 4 fields I want to compare and exclude
field_1 = [error.field_1 for error in qs2]
field_2 = [error.field_2 for error in qs2]
field_3 = [error.field_3 for error in qs2]
field_4 = [error.field_4 for error in qs2]

# Assuming this would work
qs3 = qs1.exclude(field_1__in=field_1, field_2__in=field_2, field_3__in=field_3, field_4__in=field_4)

# But ended up with 10 rows in qs3 since it doesn't loop thru the fields it just excludes it if found, which isn't ideal since some rows might be duplicate in qs1 so.
```

I then thought maybe `union()` would combine the two and exclude any duplicates between the two then I could just use an `exclude(pk__in=qs3_union)`. But I realized that's not how `union()` works.

Answer (score 0):

```
qs1 = ErrorLog.objects.filter(report=original_report) # 272 rows
qs2 = ErrorLog.objects.filter(report=new_report) # 266 rows

diff_qs = qs1.difference(qs2) # 6 rows
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.